# GetUniformLocation() returns -1

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

The code

```
GL.GetUniformLocation();
```

returns -1 for the uniform `"transform"` in the glsl code

```
#version 420

layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;

uniform mat4 transform;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = transform * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

The only other post I could find about this talked about the optimizer compiling it out, but I don't see how it could do that as it is essential in the final output of the shader. I am using Windows and the normal compiler. When I run `GL.GetError()` I get a InvalidOperation error.

The full code is

C# code:

```
    public void AddUniform(string Uniform)
    {
        int tries = 6;
        Start:
        int UniLocation = GL.GetUniformLocation(Program, Uniform);

#if DEBUG
        tries--;
        if(UniLocation == -1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(this.ToString() + " Failed DEBUG AddUniform check");
            if (tries > 0)
            {
                goto Start;
            }
        }
#endif
        Uniforms.Add(Uniform, UniLocation);
    }
```

Uniforms is a `Dictionary<string, int>`

Shader code:

```
#version 420

layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;

uniform mat4 transform = mat4(1.0);
void main()
{

    gl_Position = transform * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

The Implementation:

```
        NewWindow.Init(() =>
        {
            mesh = new MobiusEngine.NewSystems.Mesh();
            shader = new MobiusEngine.NewSystems.Shader();

            mesh.AddVerticies(new MobiusEngine.NewSystems.Vertex(new OpenTK.Vector3d(-1, -1, 0)), new MobiusEngine.NewSystems.Vertex(new OpenTK.Vector3d(0, 1, 0)), new MobiusEngine.NewSystems.Vertex(new OpenTK.Vector3d(1, -1, 0)));

            shader.AddVertexShader(MobiusEngine.NewSystems.ShaderFunctions.LoadShader("BasicVertex.vert"));
            shader.AddFragmentShader(MobiusEngine.NewSystems.ShaderFunctions.LoadShader("BasicFrag.frag"));
            shader.AddUniform("transform");

            shader.ComplieShader();

        });
        double temp = 0d;
        NewWindow.Render(() =>
        {
            shader.Bind();
            shader.SetUniformM("transform", Matrix4.CreateTranslation((float)(Math.Abs(Math.Sin(temp))), 0, 0));
            temp += Time.DeltaTime.TotalSeconds;

            mesh.Draw();
        });
```

Comment: See [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45574726/opengl-gl-getuniformlocation-always-returns-zero-0) for possible solution, you may not be targeting ES3.

Comment: Did the whole shader program actually compile and link?

Comment: yes, when I set the matrix to a default, mat4(1.0), the triangle I am rendering appears, without this, it doesn't, I also do error checking for both of these and retry when they fail.

Comment: Show the actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obviously try to query the location before the shader is compiled and the program is linked here:

> ```
>        shader.AddUniform("transform");
>
>        shader.ComplieShader();
> ```

Uniform locations are assigned during linking.